# How to get a number input from the ViewModel in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dialog

I need to request a number from the user after a command has been run. This needs to run in the view model. I've tried ACR.UserDialog, but I can't seem to figure out how to call it from the viewmodel.

Something like this:

```
void RemoveItem()
{ 
    int intQuantity = (dialog from user to get the quantity);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: incomprehensible incomplete question , please modify it to get better answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how it's incomplete.. I just need to be able to ask the user for a number input from the Viewmodel. Maybe you have some suggestions? or questions for clarification? I'm not sure how else to ask it. Thanks.

Comment: still, don't understand what *number input from the ViewModel* means .. and what is the link with ACR. write in steps what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following result with Command in viewModel.

First of all, you need to create the `AbstractViewModel`.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Acr.UserDialogs;

namespace MyCusListview
{
    public abstract class AbstractViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected AbstractViewModel(IUserDialogs dialogs)
        {
            this.Dialogs = dialogs;
        }


        protected IUserDialogs Dialogs { get; }


        protected virtual void Result(string msg)
        {
            this.Dialogs.Alert(msg);
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then implement this abstract class, do not forget to add the `IUserDialogs dialogs` in your viewmodel constructor. Then push the `dialogs.PromptAsync`, you can get the result in `input.Text`.

```
  public class PersonsViewModel: AbstractViewModel
    {   
        public ObservableCollection<Person> persons { get; set; }
        public static ObservableCollection<Person> selectItems { get; set; }

        public ICommand TextChangeCommand { protected set; get; }
       

     
        public PersonsViewModel(INavigation navigation, IUserDialogs dialogs, ContentPage page):base(dialogs)
        {

            TextChangeCommand = new Command<Person>(async (key) =>
            {
                var input = await dialogs.PromptAsync("What is your email?", "Confirm Email", "Confirm", "Cancel");

                if (input.Ok)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your email is" + input.Text);
                }

            });
        }
     }
```

When you binding the viewModel in the background code, you just use following code when init the viewmodel.

```
  public MainPage()
        {
           InitializeComponent();

            personsViewModel =  new PersonsViewModel(Navigation, UserDialogs.Instance, this);
            this.BindingContext = personsViewModel;



        }
```

Here is running result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the [samples](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/master/src/Samples/Samples/ViewModels/StandardViewModel.cs) show how to do this

```
// Dialogs is an IUserDialogs that you pass to your VM from your page
// using UserDialogs.Instance
var result = await Dialogs.PromptAsync(new PromptConfig()

  .SetTitle("Max Length Prompt")
  .SetPlaceholder("Maximum Text Length (10)")
  .SetInputMode(InputType.Name)
  .SetMaxLength(10));

// result.Text will contain the user's response
```